# C programming, int a[N]={0}; Meaning of this statement?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

For the famous problem.

There are 100 people standing in a circle numbered from 1 to 100. The first person is having a sword and kills the the person standing next to him clockwise i.e 1 kills 2 and so on. Which is the last number to remain alive? Which is the last number standing?

In the following C code for this problem.

```
void main(){
    int i=0, j; //i has the sword, j gets killed.
    int a[N]={0}; //0=not killed
    while(1){
        if(i != N-1) j = i + 1;
        else j = 0;
        while(a[j])
            if((j + 1) == N) j = 0; //loop back to 0
            else j++; //skip over the killed people
        if(i==j){ //if i is the only one left, stop
            printf("\n\n\n%d is left!", i+1);
            return;
        }
        a[j] = 1; //kill j
        printf(" %d kills %d.", i+1, j+1);
        if(j != N-1) i = j + 1;
        else i=0;
        while(a[i])
            if((i + 1) == N) i = 0;
            else i++;
    }
}
```

Please tell me meaning of `int a[N]={0};`//0=not killed in line no. 6 Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code,

```
 int a[N]={0};
```

is initializing *all* the members of the array `a` to 0.

As per the `C11` standard, chapter §6.7.9, *initalization*, (*emphasis mine*)

> **If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
>   of an aggregate**, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
>   size than there are elements in the array, **the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.**

and, for intializer value of static storage type `int`, which is *arithmetic type*,

> [...] if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;

and `a` is an array of type `int`, so it will have all it's members initialized `0` as the values. `a[0]` will be explicitly initialized to `0` (supplied), and the rest will get the implicit initialization.

FWIW, the `N` has to be a compile-time constant value, like

```
#define N 50 //or any value
```

for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

It basically tells the compiler that this will be an array of size N and will all be zero-initialized. So when you try to show the output of this array you'll see N zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat similar to :

```
memset(a, 0, N * sizeof(int))
```